# How to fetch network name from Facebook with Facebook SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch the Network list and its associated email Address from Facebook in Android. I am using the Facebook SDK for Android. But in response JSON from the Facebook, I am not getting the Network Name and the associated email address. Currently following permission are given.

```
Utility.mFacebook.authorize(LoginActivity.this,
                        new String[] { "publish_stream","read_stream", "offline_access","user_education_history", "email" },
                        Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                        facebookListener.new LoginDialogListener())
```

**UPDATE**: From Facebook developer site we can get network name in affiliation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getStandardinfo/)

**affiliations - The list of network affiliations, as affiliation elements, each of which contain year, type, status, name, and nid child elements. If no affiliations are returned, this element will be blank. The user's primary network (key: nid) will be listed first.**

getting the following response in JSON format, but no affiliation tag in response,

```
{
    "work": [
        {
            "employer": {
                "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "name": "xyz"
            },
            "start_date": "0000-00",
            "end_date": "0000-00"
        }
    ],

    "locale": "en_US",
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/abc.xyz.12",
    "education": [
        {
            "type": "College",
            "school": {
                "id": "112520115426955",
                "name": "University of Pennsylvania"
            }
        }
    ],
    "updated_time": "2012-11-01T06:31:14+0000",
    "id": "0000000000000000",
    "first_name": "XYZ",
    "timezone": 5.5,
    "username": "abc.xyz.12",
    "email": "abc@xyz.com",
    "verified": true,
    "name": "XYZ ABC",
    "last_name": "ABC",
    "gender": "male"
}
```

Please let me know, is there any permission required for same. or any other way to get this.

Thanks in Advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the FQL query to get an user's affiliation:

> select affiliations from user where uid=YOUR_UID_HERE

Example link to graph api explorer with the FQL query below.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20affiliations%20from%20user%20where%20uid%3D1060290170%0A%0A